# How can we add keyboard shortcuts to an mx:MenuBar?

Tags: apache-flex, keyboard-shortcuts, menubar

I need some assistance from the Flex experts.

I have an `mx:Menubar`, which I need to be able to open/expand based on the key pressed. For e.g., if <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> is pressed, it needs to open the 'Request' topmenu. Then if <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> is pressed, it should load the 'New request' module in the module loader. I've already implemented the `MenuBar`/module-loading functionality with the mouse, but I haven't been able to implement the keyboard shortcuts.

I found a sample solution online (**edit**: link no longer available), however, the solution directly performs the action (e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to load the 'New request' module). The menu does not open/expand when you press the shortcut as though you had hovered your mouse over it (e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open/expand the 'Request' topmenu and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to load the 'New request' module).

Has anyone attempted something like this?

Comment: please either update that link (no longer seems to be valid) or remove it. Thank you.

Comment: @gigantt.com Unfortunately, it appears that the link is no longer available (the question was asked in 2010). However, it is not possible to remove the link without making the question incomplete. Thus, it may be better to leave it as is for historical purposes.

Comment: How is it helpful to direct every reader to a dead link? How does that shed more light on the problem? I'm removing it as it's a time wasting distraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using onShow as the event handler for the shortcut , and in the handler just have it enable each menu item not perform it so it would look like

```
menuBar.menuitems.(@label=="fileTab")
```

this should ensure that you are only selecting the items and not performing their function.